# How to join a table containing 2 or more foreign key columns referring to same primary key column in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have my tables as

### Table1

Col1, 
Col2_FK1   (references Col1_PK of Table2),
Col3_FK2   (references Col1_PK of Table2)

### Table2

Col1_PK,Col2

---

I want to query on these two tables to get result based on Col1_PKand Col2 of Table2
Can anybody help me on this. Searched SO on this in vain.

---

> Table 1

[image]

> Table 2

[image]

---

The question is
Write a query to find the Emp_Name whose location preference(LP) is (either Bangalore or Mumbai) but not Chennai.

Comment: You need to add sample data to make it clear what you need. I suppose the key idea is that you need to have 2 references to Table2 and use aliases for them.

Comment: @mdahlman updated sample data

Comment: you forgot to add o/p of these tables!!

Comment: @mdahlman But two inner joins will be a overhead if it can be achieved by single join!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
SELECT t1.emp_name, 
       t2_lpt1.location, 
       t2_lpt2.location 
FROM   table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN table2 t2_lpt1 
               ON ( t1.lpt1 = t2_lpt1.code ) 
       INNER JOIN table2 t2_lpt2 
               ON ( t1.lpt2 = t2_lpt2.code ) 
WHERE  t2_lpt1.code != 33 
       AND t2_lpt2.code != 33 
       AND ( /* either Bangalore or Mumbai */ )
```

Comment: Is there more optimal solution to this? without having 2 instance of same table2?

Comment: There is still only one instance of the table. It's just that you want to use it simultaneously for 2 different things. This is Completely normal and standard. You should get exactly what you want out of this type of a solution.

Comment: But two inner joins will be a overhead if it can be achieved by single join!

Comment: You could change your query to `select 'Shalini' from dual` and it will be much quicker. But to solve the problem as you stated it where you have 2 different fields acting as FKs, you need 2 joins.